# React onClick taking an extra click to change state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that is used to setState in my App.js script. I have passed this as props to my FilteringTable.js component which calls this function when a table row is clicked.
It always takes an extra click to change the state.
How do I fix this problem? Please help

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component{

  state={
    data:[]
  }

  setStateData = rowData =>{
    this.setState({
      data:rowData
    })
  };
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className='App'>
        <Header data={this.state.data}/>  
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/filtertable" render={(props)=> <FilteringTable{...props}setStateData={rowData => this.setStateData(rowData)}/>}/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer data={this.state.data}/> 
      </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

FilteringTable.js

```
export const FilteringTable = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
    <div className="content">

      <table className="list-table" 
      {...getTableProps()}
      onClick={()=> {props.setStateData(selectedFlatRows);
        console.log("Clicked",selectedFlatRows)}}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                  {column.render('Header')}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                  {cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

The onClick function in the table component is where the function to setState is used. And it takes an extra click to change the state.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should edit your post and only add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If I strip your components down your code works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving this call to `useEffect`:

```
 useEffect(()=> {props.setStateData(selectedFlatRows)},[selectedFlatRows])
```

Comment: How would that work on click? Although to be honest the original question is not really clear.

Comment: From what I understood from the user's previous question `selectedFlatRows` is a state variable and it is updated on click, so it make sense the callback gets the previous version. I might be wrong though